# How to insert after a specific element but before another element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Explaining by example:

```
<li data-owner="1"></li>
<li data-id="1"></li>
<li data-id="2"></li>
(insert here)
<li data-owner="2"></li>
```

I want to insert between `data-owner="1"` and `data-owner="2"`, and insert last - just above `data-owner="2"`.

This do my first requirement:

```
$('li[data-owner="1"]').after('<li data-id="3"></li>');
```

But this will insert here:

```
<li data-owner="1"></li>
(insert here)
<li data-id="1"></li>
<li data-id="2"></li>
<li data-owner="2"></li>
```

Is there a way to make it insert after one element, and then move down until it finds another element and insert before that? Or find the next element `li[data-owner]` after a specific element `li[data-owner="2"]` and insert before that?

I cannot use `$('li[data-owner="2"]').before('<li data-id="3"></li>');` because I do not know the specific value of `data-owner` of the element I want to insert before.

Comment: You need to use a variable for `data-owner`, how jquery will know which data-owner needs to insert before or after?

Comment: use `$('li[data-owner]').each(function() { if( $(this).data('owner') == 2 ) { $(this).before('<li data-id="3"></li>'); } });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to want to find the next list element with a data id, and then place your insertion before that element. This can be done using [`nextAll`](https://api.jquery.com/nextall/). The example is broken out to show the steps clearer as opposed to being simply chained.

```js
var owner = 1;
var currentOwner = $('li[data-owner='+owner+']');
var nextOwner = currentOwner.nextAll('li[data-owner]:first');
nextOwner.before('<li data-id="3">(insert: li data-id="3")</li>');

//1-liner: $('li[data-owner=1']').nextAll('li[data-owner]:first').before('<li data-id="3">(insert)</li>')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li data-owner="1">data-owner="1"</li>
<li data-id="1">data-id="1"</li>
<li data-id="2">data-id="2"</li>
<li data-owner="2">data-owner="2"</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines?

```
<ul>
<li data-owner="1">a</li>
<li data-id="1">b</li>
<li data-id="2">c</li>
<li data-owner="2">d</li>
</ul>
```

javascript:

```
var owner_flag = 0;
jQuery("li[data-owner]").each(function(){
    if(owner_flag == 1)
    {
        owner_flag == 0;
        jQuery(this).before('<li data-id="3">next</li>');
    }
    if(jQuery(this).attr("data-owner") == "1")
    {
        owner_flag = 1;
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u7m5mkL6/